# Silverlight page not catching input events

Tags: silverlight, xaml, event-handling, user-input, event-routing

I have been attempting to handle the KeyDown event of a UserControl (page) in my Silverlight application, but there seems to be some strange behaviour on the part of Silverlight user input functionality. The event is not getting raised under any circumstance. I have even tried attaching the event handler to each container control within the UserControl, but still with no luck. Indeed, the Silverlight user input "event routing" system is quite novel and seems rather strange to me, so perhaps it is just a misunderstanding on my part, though I have rather clueless about how to proceed.

The following code is a template of the particular page with which I am testing.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.CreditsPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             KeyDown="UserControl_KeyDown">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Border>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center">
                A line of text.<LineBreak />
                <LineBreak />
                A line of text.<LineBreak />
                <LineBreak />
                A line of text.<LineBreak />
                <LineBreak />
                A line of text.<LineBreak />
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In WPF, the obvious solution for such an issue would be to handle the PreviewKeyDown event, but unfortunately this is not available in Silverlight 2. Any ideas would be welcome (and a short explanation of why Silverlight event routing is behaving as it is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage the user input from the main UIElement : Application.Current.RootVisual

```
Application.Current.RootVisual.KeyDown += Application_KeyDown
```

Then you can handle in the Application_KeyDown method all user inputs from the keyboard.

You can also look at this issue : [Handling KeyDown event in a Canvas](http://www.silverlightissues.com/issue.php5?i=18)

Answer (score 1):

I tried the xaml that you provided and did not have a problem handing the KeyDown event.

One thing that could be causing it: the Silverlight plugin will only see input events if it is focused. So try and click on the Silverlight content in the browser to give it input focus before pressing the keys.

Let me know if that solves your problem or not.

Comment: Ah, it seems like it was in fact the root UserControl page that was catching the KeyDown event. The situation I described in my post was slightly inaccurate because the UserControl specified in that XAML was in fact the content/child of a SwitcherPage.

Comment: (contd.) So my question now is: can I force the content page of the SwitcherPage to capture user input events? If I can't, there's an easy work-around in handling the events in the SwitcherPage and then directing them, but I'm curious if there's a more direct solution. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: You could do as the other poster suggests and handle the event on the RootVisual. If you do this you want to make sure that you remove your handler from this event when you remove your UserControl from the tree; otherwise your UserControl will continue to receive events.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the best solution. I'm attaching the event handler to every page, but with a check for the active page at the start of each. Cheers...